# How to divide every element in a list with each element in another list in R?

Tags: r, division

I am trying to check if `all` the `elements` of `list` A are divisible with all the elements of `list` B. if the remainder is `0` for all the `elements`, I want to `print` the corresponding `elements` of A.

my example code so far

```
first<-c(2,4,6,8,10,12)
second<-c(2,3)

for (i in first){
    for (j in second){
        if (i%%j==0){ #if any elements in first is divisible by all elements in second
            print(i)
            }
        }
    }
```

But it gives me output like this

```
[1] 2
[1] 4
[1] 6
[1] 6
[1] 8
[1] 10
[1] 12
[1] 12
```

I was expecting something `[1] 6,12`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `outer` to get the modulus of each combination, and then `rowSums` to see which don't leave a remainder,

```
first[rowSums(outer(first, second, `%%`)) == 0]
#[1]  6 12
```

Comment: Nice! I was thinking `first[first %% prod(second) == 0]` but that screws up when `second` is something like `c(2,3,6)`. Just for fun, any way this could be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Your code prints out all the numbers in `first` which are divisible by *any* number in `second`. Have a look at the [all function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/all.html), you are looking for something like

```
first<-c(2,4,6,8,10,12)
second<-c(2,3)

for (i in first){
    if (all(i %% second == 0)){ #if any elements in first is divisible by all elements in second
        print(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this returns the correct output. Have you checked what it does?

Comment: Yes, it returns the correct output (if I understand the question correctly). I updated my answer with a more complete code example.

Answer (score 0):

Oliver have right, to complete code you should do something like:

```
for (i in first){
  if(all(i%%second==0)){
    print(i)
  }
}
```